# Email to case Settings - Comments REPLY-TO Address

Tags: email2case, case-object, comments

I was testing case comments, and noticed that every time a case comment is created, the customer gets an email notification about the comment. When the customer replies to that email (comment notification), it can either be set to go to **no-reply@salesforce.com** or to the case owner (myself - admin).

I was wondering, would it be possible to change the FROM (**REPLY-TO**) email address for case comments that the customer receives? such that when the customer replies, it should go to any email address that I set and/or to Salesforce?

I did my research, played around with all possible configurations in Support Settings and Email-to-Case but couldn't find a solution. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using org wide email address

> If your organization requires users to share a common email alias, you can define a list of organization-wide addresses for each user profile. Organization-wide addresses define a common email address that a user profile can use. When sending email from Salesforce, users with these profiles can choose a different From address than the email address they have defined. Replies are delivered to the organization-wide address.
>   For example, assume your organization has several users under a single Support Profile. A Support Profile can be associated with an email address called support@acme.com and a Display Name of Acme Support. When Support Profile users send an outbound email through Salesforce, they can choose to have their From address appear as support@acme.com instead of their own Salesforce email address.
>   The highlighted sections in the following image represents the changes to the From address and Display Name that the recipient of an email might see:
>   [image]
>   After an organization-wide address is verified, it is available as a From address when sending an email or an email alert.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help. I actually have this implemented, and is working really well just the way I wanted. My issue was that I wanted a way to define/select a FROM address for outgoing COMMENTS NOTIFICATIONS as well such that when users (including outsiders) reply to that notification email, it should go to (FROM/REPLY-TO address) support@acme.com, and not to the comment creator or noreply@salesforce.com. I even reached out to Salesforce tech support, and was told this functionality is not available currently, and can be achieved only with custom programming.